# How do I make jQuery code execute when a checkbox is checked programatically somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form with a dropdown box (`<select id="state"> ... </select>` tag). I have a checkbox next to it (`<input type="checkbox" id="not-from-US" />`).

The HTML dropdown item has a list of all United States stas (MO,TX,AL,etc.). But if the user is not from the United States, he/she checks the "Not from US" checkbox. Now in jQuery, I have programmed the checkbox (via `.change()`) to generate an additional field for selecting a country when the checkbox is checked. It also makes the dropdown select the "N/A" option.

I also programmed my form so that if the user selects "N/A" from the "States" dropdown menu, the "Not from US" checkbox gets checked. But how do I link the two events together? When the checkbox is programatically checked, the anonymous function for when the checkbox is checked does not fire.

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to attach the sample code. Here it is:

```
------------------index.php------------------

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <select id="state">
       <option value="None">None</option>
       <option selected="true" value="AL">AL</option> 
       <option value="AK">AK</option> 
       <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
       <!--etc.-->
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" id="not-from-usa" name="not-from-usa" />
</form>

------------------main.js------------------

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#state').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "None") {
            $('#not-from-usa').attr('checked','checked');    // This is the important bit.
            // So now the #not-from-usa checkbox is checked. So the code below should execute, right?
        } else {
            $('#not-from-usa).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });

    $('#not-from-usa').change(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
            // Create an input element that the user can enter a country
            // Code omitted for clarity.

            // The code in here should execute once the checkbox is checked or unchecked.
            $('#state').val("None");    // Set the dropdown to the "None" selection
        } else {
            // Remove the extra input element that lets the user enter a country.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "programatically checked" from the server side (already checked in generated html) or from the client side?

Comment: What prevents you from just triggering the `change` event?

Comment: Sorry guys! I have added a code sample to show you what I'm talking about.
I know how to trigger the change() event in the traditional sense... however, I can't get the change() event to trigger when the checkbox is set to be checked using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function checkbox.click() rather then setting checkbox.checked = true;

I have edited this post.

Comment: Ooh, you were just faster than me. Anyway, I can confirm this works: http://jsfiddle.net/cmacrander/fr94m/

Comment: I'm sorry... I did not mean to downvote this, but Stackoverflow won't let me undo it. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to change the post a little before Stackoverflow will let me do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ gives you what you want.

With trigger you dispatch the event. So just add one $("checkbox").trigger('click'); 
That should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that the triggers don't seem to be chained. One event triggers another, but that other event doesn't in turn trigger another trigger. That's the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript,you can use the `.checked` attribute:

```
if(document.getElementById("not-from-US").checked) {
   //checked, do something
} else {
   //not checked, do something.. 
}
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question being asked.